# How to match the string after first character in a line

Tags: python, regex

Find the string of first match

```
s = '''
Name Mak How are you Name non Name anonymouse
Name Mak1 How are you Name non1
Name Mak2 How are you Name non2
'''
```

How to extract first Name

```
My Expected Out
['Mak', 'Mak1', 'Mak2']
```

Pseudo code

```
import re
re.findall(r'?Name (([\w]+)',s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
>>> s = '''
... Name Mak How are you Name non Name anonymouse
... Name Mak1 How are you Name non1
... Name Mak2 How are you Name non2
... '''
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)^Name (\w+)', s)
['Mak', 'Mak1', 'Mak2']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?m)` Enable multiline mode
- `^`: Start
- `Name`: Match literal text followed by a space
- `(\w+)`: Match 1+ word characters and capture in group #1

Comment: in your code, where you have mentioned, that to avoid new line?

Comment: When we use `(?m)` or multiline mode then we can match `^` at start of every new line.

Comment: one more querry, if we want to extract  second 'Name' is there any hack to do

Comment: If you want last `Name` then use `re.findall(r'.+ Name (\w+)', s)`

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `str.split`.

**Ex:**

```
s = '''
Name Mak How are you Name non Name anonymouse
Name Mak1 How are you Name non1
Name Mak2 How are you Name non2
'''

print([line.split()[1] for line in s.splitlines() if line.startswith('Name')])
```

**Output:**

```
['Mak', 'Mak1', 'Mak2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r'Name\s+([^\s]+).+', m)
```

Details

```
# Name - matches Name literally

# \s+ - matches one or more of white spaces

# ([^\s]+) - match one or more characters other from whitespace \s and store it inside first capturing group

# .+ - match one or more of any characters (except newline)
```